# Android T9 Search Contacts ( Smart Dialer )

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I would like to implement T9 search like android native dialer or TrueCaller dialer. What I have achieved till now is:-

Convert keystrokes to string patterns like if I press 2 on dialer it would gives me - "abc" "ac" "ca" and so on

Now I made a query

String selection = Utility.getSelectionLikeWithIn(mmemonics);

Cursor query = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, null, null);'

public static String getSelectionLikeWithIn(List mmemonics) {

```
    String selection = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < mmemonics.size(); i++) {
        selection = selection + " display_name LIKE '";
        selection = selection + mmemonics.get(i);

        if (i == mmemonics.size() - 1){
            selection = selection + "%'";


        }else {
            selection = selection + "%' OR";
        }
    }
    return selection;
}'
```

above method convert Arraylist of string to where clause

where display_name Like 'ab%' OR display_name LIKE 'abc%' and so on......

well this give me the inefficient result and app crash due to complex query.....

Please suggest me how can I perform a query to match like my keystroke or os their any other way in ContactsProvider to perform such smart search

Answer (score 6):

If you're going to refresh the list on each digit press this technique won't work because it'll be soooo slow.

The better option would be to read **all** contact names from the `Contacts` DB, and store them in a simple `ArrayList<String>` or similar collection, preferably while reading the names convert them `toLowerCase()` to make search easier in the next step.

Next, for each digit pressed, build a [regular expression pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) from the entered digits, for example "234" would convert to the pattern `.*[abc][def][ghi].*`

After building the pattern, iterate through the names list and return names that match the pattern.

Comment: Thanks alot bro, you make my day